# Weak form of $-\frac{d}{dx} \left[(1+x) \frac{du}{dx}\right]$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am doing some self studying on J.N. Reddy's book, *An Introduction to the finite element method*, 1st edition. (This was the only one available at the local library).

In exercise 2.12, one reads

> Compute the coefficient matrix and the right size of the N-parameter Ritz system of the equation
>
> \begin{aligned}
> \frac{d}{dx} \left((1+x) \frac{du}{dx}\right) & = 0 \\ 0<x<1
> \end{aligned}
>   with conditions
>
> $u(0)$ = 1 and $u(1)=1$.

In the answer, it says that the right-size N parameter is

> \begin{aligned}
> l_i = \frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}
> \end{aligned}

However, I always find $l_i = 0$.

My procedure was the following.

> Using Ritz method,
>
> \begin{aligned}
> 0 = -\int_0^1 v\frac{d}{dx}\left((1+x)\frac{du}{dx}\right)dx
> \end{aligned}
>
> Integrating by parts,
>
> \begin{aligned}
> 0 = -\int_0^1 v\frac{d}{dx}\left((1+x)\frac{du}{dx}\right)dx = -v(1+x)\frac{du}{dx}  |_0^1 + \int^1_0 (1+x)\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{du}{dx}dx
> \end{aligned}
>
> As $u$ is specified at $x=0$ and $x=1$, $v(0) = v(1) = 0$. Therefore
>
> \begin{aligned}
> -v(1+x)\frac{du}{dx}  |_0^1 = 0
> \end{aligned}
>
> And we are left with
>
> \begin{aligned}
> 0 = -\int_0^1 v\frac{d}{dx}\left((1+x)\frac{du}{dx}\right)dx =  \int^1_0 (1+x)\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{du}{dx}dx
> \end{aligned}
>
> Thus the Bilinear form is
>
> \begin{aligned}
> B(u,v) =  \int^1_0 (1+x)\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{du}{dx}dx
> \end{aligned}
>
> and
>
> \begin{aligned}
> l(v) = 0
> \end{aligned}

Could any one tell me what I got wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood my mistake, and it was caused by misunderstanding the notation.

Given an approximate answer

\begin{align}
u_N = \phi_0 + \sum_{i=1}^N c_i\phi_i
\end{align}

We cannot say that $l_i = l(\phi_i)$, but

\begin{align}
l_i = l(\phi_i) - B(\phi_i, \phi_0)
\end{align}

That way, choosing $\phi_0 = x$ and $\phi_i = x^i(1-x)$, we find

\begin{align}
l_i =-B(\phi_i, \phi_0) = -\int_0^1 x (1-x) x^i dx = -\int_0^1 x^{i+1}-x^{i+2} dx = -\frac{1}{i+1} + \frac{1}{i+2} = \frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}
\end{align}